# Android call method inside onClickListener with external parameters

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener

So, I'm developing an app for my graduation final project and in my app I have a layout with an imageView and a textView, to set the content of these elements I receive an ArrayList as a parameter and use the setText(), and it works.

But my Arraylist has more than one element, and my big problem is that I want to change the content of the imageView and the textView when I click in a button.
The way I was thinking was that when I click the button it will increment the value and change the content of the objects for the next element inside the arrayList.

I've faced problems with global variables inside onClickListeners, but I solved them with auxiliar methods, but this time that doesn't work since I need to increment the value of the iteration inside the button event.

Can you guys please help me with suggestions or tell me what I'm I doing wrong?

I hope you understand my problem, and I'm sorry if I didn't explain me well, feel free to ask any questions and request more blocks of code if what I post isn't enough.

Thanks in advance to all you guys, i apreciate all the help you can give me!

---

### To get the data from my db and store it into an arraylist

```
private ArrayList<Exercises> getExercisesSelectedPlan() {
    ArrayList<ProgramExercises> arrayList_programExercises = new ArrayList<();
    ArrayList<Exercises> arrayList_exercises = new ArrayList<>();
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinishAquecimento);

    //with the id of the selected plan, select all the exercises from the plan and load them into the layout
    int idProgram = getIdPlan();

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryProgramExercises = "SELECT * FROM PROGRAM_EXERCISES WHERE PROGRAM_ID_PROGRAM = " + "'" + idProgram + "'" + " ORDER BY ORDER_EX ASC";
    Cursor cursorProgramExercises = db.rawQuery(queryProgramExercises, null);
    int numRows = cursorProgramExercises.getCount();
    if (numRows > 0) {
        cursorProgramExercises.moveToFirst();
        while (numRows > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursorProgramExercises.getCount(); i++) {
                ProgramExercises nProgramExercises = new ProgramExercises();
                nProgramExercises.setIdProgramExercises(cursorProgramExercises.getInt(0));
                nProgramExercises.setOrder(cursorProgramExercises.getString(1));
                nProgramExercises.setRepetition(cursorProgramExercises.getInt(2));
                nProgramExercises.setIdExercises(cursorProgramExercises.getInt(3));
                arrayList_programExercises.add(nProgramExercises);
                numRows--;
            }
        }
    }

    //for each select result from program_exercises i have to select the exercise with the id correspondent to nProgramExercies.getidExercises
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList_programExercises.size(); i++) {
        String queryExercises = "SELECT * FROM EXERCISES WHERE ID_EXERCISES = " + "'" + arrayList_programExercises.get(i).getIdExercises() + "'";
        Cursor cursorExercises = db.rawQuery(queryExercises, null);
        cursorExercises.moveToNext();

        if (cursorExercises.getCount() > 0) {
            Exercises exercises = new Exercises();
            for (int j = 0; j < cursorExercises.getCount(); j++) {
                exercises.setIdExercises(cursorExercises.getInt(0));
                exercises.setMedia(cursorExercises.getString(1));
                exercises.setDesignation(cursorExercises.getString(2));
                exercises.setIdExercisesPhase(cursorExercises.getInt(3));
                arrayList_exercises.add(exercises);
                cursorExercises.moveToNext();
            }
            cursorExercises.close();
        }
    }

    cursorProgramExercises.close();
    db.close();
    databaseHelper.close();
}
```

---

### Where I want to change the content of the textview and increment the iteration when I click btnNext

```
 public void prepareExercise(final ArrayList<Exercises> exercises) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_execute_ex_warmup);

    TextView txtPrepare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAquecimento);
    ImageView imageExercise = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAquecimento);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinishAquecimento);
    txtPrepare.setText(exercises.get(1).getDesignation());
    imageExercise.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgTest);

    for (int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++) {
        if (exercises.get(i).getIdExercisesPhase() == 1) {
            txtPrepare.setText(exercises.get(i).getDesignation());
            System.out.println("------ TEST" + exercises.get(i).getDesignation());
        }
    }


    //Click Next Button
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //for (int i = 1; i < exercises.size(); i++) {
            //TextView txtPrepare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAquecimento);
            //txtPrepare.setText(exercises.get(finalI).getDesignation());
            //}
            //executeExercise(); //next Exercise
        }
    });
}
```

---

### How I invoke the previous method

```
        prepareExercise(getExercisesSelectedPlan());
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, what's not working?

Comment: it only shows the first element in the arraylist when i run the app and i cant increment the "for" by clicking the button, i need a way to increment the value of the "for" that is outside the onClickListener, when i press the button to change for the second element in my arraylist @UdiIdan

Comment: I don't totally understand why you're using for loops if you want to display one value.
A simple solution will be to decale an int as a class member and then increment it in btnNext and then txtPrepare.setText(exercises.get(i).getDesignation());

Comment: that still does not work, but maybe because i think my arraylist is returning more elements than it should, i only have 2 elements where ->         if (exercises.get(i).getIdExercisesPhase() == 1) { but its returning 4 elements all with the same description..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding correctly.

If you just want to update the views each time the button is clicked the easiest way would be just to create a variable and store the position of the array list.

```
public int listIncrement = 0;
private TextView txtPrepare;
private ImageView imageExercise;
```

Then in your prepareExercise() method

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(listIncrement <= excersises.size()) {
            executeExercise(excersises, listIncrement); //next Exercise
            listIncrement++;
        }
    }
});
```

and then in executeExercise(ArrayList exercises, int position) //guessed method name, can be whatever you like

```
txtPrepare.setText(exercises.get(position).getDesignation());
imageExercise.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgTest);
```